# Append or prepend a salt to a password?

Tags: passwords, cryptography, hash, salt

Does it matter how I add a salt to a password in my application: by **appending** it or by **prepending**?

```
# 1
res = sha256(salt + password)

# 2
res2 = sha256(password + salt)
```

I've been told that the 2nd option is better.

Comment: Presumably if the hashing algorithm is worth it's salt (pun intended!), then it really shouldn't matter. Just be consistent, as the output will be different.

Comment: You're very much in the wrong track, and should really read the top answers in ["How to securely hash passwords?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)

Comment: it mattered more for MD5, doesn't matter at all for SHA3, and doesn't matter much with SHA2

Answer (score 2):

This scenario doesn't really apply to password storage, but more for trying to use a standard hash to validate user input.

The reason data+salt is better is because it makes it more difficult to perform a [Length Extention Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack)   The assumption here is that the user does not control the salt, but does control the data.  If the user can control the end of the input to a hash, he/she can control/predict what the hash will look like.  This [link](https://blog.skullsecurity.org/2012/everything-you-need-to-know-about-hash-length-extension-attacks) can give you a better idea of how length extention attacks work

Also, don't ever use sha256 to hash passwords.  Use some sort of Key Derivation Function, like BCrypt.

Comment: `don't ever use sha256 to encrypt passwords.` -- 1) why? 2) it's not encrypting

Comment: SHA256 is too fast.  An attacker who is cracking the hashes can attempt billions of hashes per second with non-KDR hash algorithms given some decent hardware.  A KDR is designed to be much slower, as in thousands of guesses per second or lower  This significantly increases the amount of time you have between a database being compromised and the passwords being discovered.  It buys you more time to discover the breach, and reset your user's passwords.

Comment: Length extension is not a relevant concern for password hashing.  A length extension attack here would allow the attacker to construct the correct hash for a salt/password combination that would not exist in the password database, and thus is useless.

Comment: That's a much cleaner explanation than I gave in the first line of my answer.  I may steal it :)